# How to update a control in the code behind in Avalonia?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to update a canvas according to selected item in a grid.
I'm using the event OnSelected() but **how can I find the canvas to update it**?

<s>The official documentation talk about [view activation](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/concepts/reactiveui/view-activation#code-behind-reactiveui-bindings) but I'm unable to make it work... (The documentation is not very noob friendly to be honest).</s>
Edit: It's ReactUI and I'm using MVVM, so I should try to access the component directly in the code behind. **How can I do that?**

**View:**
I've name the canvas 'viewer' it's the one I want to update in the code behind

```xml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LocalArena.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="LocalArena.Views.MapsView"
             x:DataType="vm:MapsViewModel">
  <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*" RowDefinitions="*,2*">
      <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform">
          <Canvas x:Name="viewer" Width="200" Height="100" MaxWidth="200" MaxHeight="100" Background="Yellow" Margin="3"/>
      </Viewbox>
      <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding MapItems}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMapItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True"
                GridLinesVisibility="All" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
      </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewModel:**
I may miss an MVVM namespace? or my ViewModel should inherit from another class?

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

public partial class MapsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private MapItem? _selectedMapItem;
    partial void OnSelectedMapItemChanged(MapItem? value)
    {
        // I want to update the Canvas 'viewer' here
        // What's the syntax or method to use?
        Debug.WriteLine("Map selection changed");
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MapItem> MapItems { get; }
    private List<Map> _maps;
    public MapsViewModel()
    {
        _maps = new List<Map>()
        {
            new Map{ Seed = "seed-001", Type="Imported", SizeX=24, SizeY=12 },
            new Map{ Seed = "seed-002", Type="Imported", SizeX=12, SizeY=6 },
        };

        MapItems = new ObservableCollection<MapItem>(_maps.Select(x => new MapItem(x.Seed, x.Type)).ToList());
    }
}

public record MapItem(string Seed, string Type);

public class Map
{
    public string Seed { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int SizeX { get; set; }
    public int SizeY { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject
{
}
```

Comment: That View Activation is a part of ReactiveUI, but your [ObservableProperty] attribute suggests you are using CommunityToolkit.MVVM.  Which is it?  Your canvas already has a name, In Avalonia 11, you should be able to access it directly by name.

Comment: I'm indeed using the CommunityToolkit.MVVM. I'm new to Avalonia and from your comment I deduce that you cannot use MVVM and ReactUI at the same time?... I've tried access the canvas directly by name but it didn't work. What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: I'm not going to say you can't, because you probably can, but they mostly do when same thing.  They are both MVVM frameworks.  The syntax is to just access "viewer" as a field.  When you give a control a name it becomes directly accessible by that name within the scope of the user control, even in code behind.

Comment: It does not work for me. Is there any namespace that i should add or anything else? I'm using Avalonia 11.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... The 'viewer' is accessible in the code behind as a property...but not in the ViewModel... :D

The way to do the update for the 'Viewer' is with a [ContenControl](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/reference/controls/contentcontrol)